# Problem when editing the mesh

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have a problem with Mixamo at the time of rigging because it builds four fingers instead of five so I figures that the last finger it has to be a bit far.

I select the finger and when dragging this happens.  I have noticed that this happens because not all the vertex / faces of the finger are selected.  Although I select everything.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to use the X-ray mode (Shift+Z) to be sure you have selected the whole finger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like many of the finger's faces aren't selected.

Try pressing <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to enter *x-ray* mode.  This will allow you to select *through* an object.

Comment: Yes it moved now without problems, never thought of doing it with the x-ray. Very much appreciated!